# how to convert a vertical list to panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a list from a webscraper that makes a log file in a vertical list from.

example:

```
    21-Oct-19 14:46:14 - Retrieving data from https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/search.html?category=0.93&page=1&product_category=2.93.3904.69&sub_category=1.93.3904
0                          21-Oct-19 14:46:14 - Found:                                                                                                             
1    Title: Nesten ubrukt Canon 17-40 mm vidvinkell...                                                                                                             
2                                      Price: 4�900 kr                                                                                                             
3    Link: https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/ad.html?...                                                                                                             
4                          21-Oct-19 14:46:14 - Found:                                                                                                             
5    Title: Nesten ubrukt Canon 17-40 mm vidvinkell...                                                                                                             
6                                      Price: 4�900 kr                                                                                                             
7    Link: https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/ad.html?...                                                                                                             
8                          21-Oct-19 14:46:14 - Found:                                                                                                             
9    Title: Nesten ubrukt Canon 17-40 mm vidvinkell...                                                                                                             
10                                     Price: 4�900 kr                                                                                                             
11   Link: https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/ad.html?...                                                                                                             
12                         21-Oct-19 14:46:14 - Found:                                                                                                             
13   Title: Nesten ubrukt Canon 17-40 mm vidvinkell...
```

Can i convert it intro readble dataframe for Pandas ?

example:

```
title           price      link
canon 100mm     6900kr     https
canon 50mm      100r       https
canon 17mm      63530kr    https
```

my code right now look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('finn.no-2019-10-21-.log', sep ="Line", engine='python')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
title = 1,5,9,13,17,21
price = 2,6,10,14,18,22
link = 3,7,11,15,19,23

print(df)
```

can i do anything with the numbers in the original row to convert to a more traditinal dataframe ?

Comment: read_csv already gives a dataframe: the line below is redundant. As per your question, the “sep” argument serves as the separator to break the contents of a line into columns. Judging by the complexity of your data I doubt it’d help, though: you’ll likely have to do it in Python with some string manipulation and then pass it to pandas.

Comment: Since this is web content output from `https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/search.html?category=0.93&page=1&product_category=2.93.3904.69&sub_category=1.93.3904` you may actually have better luck [scraping](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-web-scrape-with-python-in-4-minutes-bc49186a8460) the data directly using something like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [scrapy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-crawl-a-web-page-with-scrapy-and-python-3) versus dumping it to a log, and then trying to parse.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you:

```
with open('finn.no-2019-10-21-.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    clean = [line.strip() for line in lines]

    title = [j.split('Title: ')[1] for j in clean if j.startswith('Title: ')]
    price = [k.split('Price: ')[1] for k in clean if k.startswith('Price: ')]
    link = [l.split('Link: ')[1] for l in clean if l.startswith('Link: ')]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[title, price, link], columns=['Title', 'Price', 'Link'])
```

Comment: IMO for title you should set the `maxsplit` kwarg of `str.split` to `1` in order to get the whole title, otherwise there would be extracted only `Nesten` for all articles.

Comment: i think it's gonna work, I just have a problem with the .log file. the webscraper wright down the same info over and over.

Comment: @zipa i got in in a ways. but i need to #df=pd.DataFrame.....

i can do print(title) or print(price)

Answer (score 0):

from help of @zipa i got it right:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('finn.no-2019-10-22-.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    clean = [line.strip() for line in lines]

    titles = [j.split('Title: ')[1] for j in clean if j.startswith('Title: ')]
    prices = [k.split('Price: ')[1] for k in clean if k.startswith('Price: ')]
    links = [l.split('Link: ')[1] for l in clean if l.startswith('Link: ')]


    output = []

    for title, price, link in zip(titles, prices, links):
        articles = {}
        articles['titles'] = title
        articles['prices'] = price
        articles['links'] = link
        output.append(articles)



    df = pd.DataFrame(data=output)

    print(df)
```